# Local-only version of `hg outgoing`?

Tags: mercurial

The command

```
hg outgoing
```

compares the local repo to the default push location; it accesses the push location to do it.

I'd like to ask the question "have I checked in changes in my local repo since my last `hg push`?" without having to access the remote repo.

It seems like there might be enough info in the local repo to figure that out; if so, is there a command to determine that?

Comment: [MercurialEclipse](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialEclipse) has the feature. It shows number of pending commits on the right hand from branch name, e.g. `↑ 10`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do it.  Tracking what has been pushed would be slightly tricky because you can push to  multiple places. And you can pull from multiple places.  So I could push to X then push to Y then pull from Z and my 'hg outgoing X' output is difficult to predict local-only.

That said you could use a command like this:

```
hg tag --local --force -r tip pushed
```

That creates a local-only tag pointing to the current tip.  If you always run that after pushing you'll always know what was last pushed.

You could create a post-push hook to do that in your .hgrc:

```
[hook]
post-push = hg tag --local --force -r tip pushed
```

Comment: In the last couple of lines, shouldn't that be the `outgoing` hook, not the `commit` hook?

Comment: Thanks, Niall.  I actually wanted the post-push hook, since that's what we're tracking, but post-commit was definitely wrong.